Can't connect package Barrier in Ubuntu 24.04
Unfortunately, when attempting to use Barrier to share the keyboard and mouse with another computer, the application does not function properly. It appears that it is not yet compatible with version 24.04. Do you have any suggestions for resolving this issue?

Have you tried to run it in a X11 session instead of Wayland ?

Latest update on their sourceforge page is 3 years old, so it it plausible that Ubuntu 24.04 or Wayland isn't supported.
Log an error to the maintainers, please, if the project is actively maintained at all.

"With Ubuntu 22.04, Barrier works correctly. However, with version 24.04, it appears that Wayland is not compatible. If my memory serves me correctly, I recall that Ubuntu 22.04 initially had the same issue. After a few months, a patch was released, and since then, it has been functioning properly.

Barrier has been forked as https://github.com/input-leap/input-leap, and it seems to have preliminary Wayland support on Gnome, but dev progress still seems on the slow side.  You might just revert to X11 for now.
